# AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method isn't respected?

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I applied this aspect:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method)] // regular methods, excluding ctors!
public class WmiClassMethodAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public WmiClassMethodAspect() { ApplyToStateMachine = false; } // PostSharp Express edition...

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        //base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        //base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

over certain `namespace`'s class:

```
[assembly: WmiClassMethodAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "OperatingSystemsWmi.*", 
    AttributePriority = 10, ApplyToStateMachine = false, 
    AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

But if it doesn't respect the `AttributeTargetElements` setting: it enters `WmiClassMethodAspect.OnEntry` and `WmiClassMethodAspect.OnExit` for properties too (`set_MyProperty` and `get_MyProperty`, for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because *MulticastTargets.Method* treats property accessors as methods (which they are). Note that *MulticastTarget.Property* specifies property (method group) for purposes of e.g. *LocationLevelAspect*.

To produce the intended behavior, you would need to add an exclusion for property getters and setters based their name:

```
[assembly: WmiClassMethodAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "OperatingSystemsWmi.*", 
           AttributePriority = 10, AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method, 
           AttributeTargetMembers = "get_*", AttributeExclude = true)]

[assembly: WmiClassMethodAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "OperatingSystemsWmi.*", 
           AttributePriority = 10, ApplyToStateMachine = false, AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method, 
           AttributeTargetMembers = "set_*", AttributeExclude = true)]
```

EDIT:
If you want this in one attribute, you can use regular expressions:

```
[assembly: WmiClassMethodAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "OperatingSystemsWmi.*", 
           AttributePriority = 10, ApplyToStateMachine = false, 
           AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method,
           AttributeTargetMembers = "regex:^(?!get_|set_).+")]
```

This is probably the most succinct solution.

Comment: Can I set this exclusion on the aspect itself?

Comment: No, you would need to use e.g. *IAspectProvider* and AssemblyLevelAspect and explicitly provide the aspect to methods you would like. Other option though is to use regular expression on the "positive" attribute (see my edit for details).